# How to find bandwidth hog with pfSense?

Tags: networking, pfsense

We have a little box running pfSense with one ADSL line connected. Someone is saturating the ADSL line with an upload that is taking up the whole line and unfortunately I am too n00b with pfSense and networking to know how to identify which computer.

I believe pftop is the answer to my problem but...how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can watch monitor live using Status / Traffic Graph.
[image]

Or you could use the ntop or BandwidthD package to monitor over.